# How to separate Voiced Part from a Speech Signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am writing a MATLAB code for a sound conversion system, i have a speech signal and i want to separate/extract the voiced part from it. How can it be done in MATLAB?

p.s: I have already plotted the cepstrum plot of the speech signal. But I want the voiced part in order to estimate the pitch of the speech signal!

Comment: Look up the Cocktail Party Problem.... specifically [Independent Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis).  A good MATLAB library that I know of is here: http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/.  However, I can't really determine whether this will work unless I have access to that audio signal.  Can you please share it?

Comment: A quick look at the references suggests the voiced and unvoiced part of a single speaker's signal can be separable using zero crossing counting methods or short time Fourier transforms because they have different oscillatory behavior (the voiced part oscillates faster). If there are multiple speakers in the signal you need to do some sort of blind source separation, @rayryeng suggestion of ICA as one approach is a good one to try.